# Novel Blurb Corpus

Tags: data-request, corpora

I am looking for a corpus of fiction book blurbs.

With at least 10,000 entries.
Preferably with a lot more.

I do not care if it is a single publisher (etc) or many.

It should be annotated with author, publisher etc.
Ideally would be annotate with Genre and Subgenre as well.

Comment: Do you mean "fiction" books, or that the blurbs should be "fictional"?

Comment: Fiction Books. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blurbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blurb), or short descriptive material to promote a book, may be impossible to legally share do to individual copyrights of the authors or publishers.

The [Goodreads API](http://www.goodreads.com/api/) has many endpoints, and they include this note:

> Book cover images, descriptions, and other data from third party sources might be excluded, because we do not have a license to distribute these data via our API.

In contrast, the book metadata can be shared (ISBN, author, publisher, etc). See, for example, the [Book-Crossing Dataset](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/).

So, in order to get a big data set of blurbs, you'd have to contact (large) publishers and ask for access. I noticed you have university affiliation, so you should mention that it is for non-commercial purposes.